# Isomorphism of higher homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Any help on answering the following question will be much appreciated.

Question:

Let $(X,B,b)$ be a based pair of spaces in which B is a pointed retract of $X$. Show that for $n \ge2$, that $$ \pi_n(X,x) \cong \pi_n(B,x) \oplus \pi_n(X,B,x)$$

Comment: FWIW, one does not *prove* a question, one *answers* it. You can *solve* a problem, and *prove* a statement.

Comment: As for your question, show that in the long exact sequence for the homotopy groups the maps that go from B to X are split homomorphisms using the retractions.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will work with that.

Comment: I proved it. Thank you once again.

Comment: **Please** write a complete answer so that the question does not remain unanswered.